# C++ print descending then ascending pattern of zeroes recursivel

Tags: c++, recursion

So I have to do this recursive function that prints out the following output:

```
000 
00
0
00 
000
```

Here is a program I wrote. How do I get the second half to work?

```
#include<iostream>

void printZpattern2(int x){
    int count = 0;
    int y = x;
    int z = x;
    for (int i=0; i<x; i++){
        cout << "0";
        count ++;
    }
    cout << endl;
    if (x == 1){
        printReverseZ(y + 1);
    }
    while (x =! 1){
        printZpattern2(x -1);
    }
}

int main(){
    printZpattern2(5);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Okay, thank you for sharing.  What is your question?

Comment: How do I make this work

Comment: Define what you mean by "get the second half to work"

Comment: Please note that `x =! 1` does not do what you think it does.  That will set `x` to zero.

Comment: Once it gets to printing a single zero, how can I get the function to output the increasing zeroes until reaching the same number of zeroes.

Comment: There is some valuable information about your problem here: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: super helpful..

Comment: It's customary when asking a question about why code is not working to show the output you are getting.  When providing full source code, you should ensure it compiles (unless asking a question about a compilation error).  The program you have shown here will not even compile, because you have not provided the `printReverseZ` function.  Furthermore, the desired output you have shown depicting a maximum of 3 zeros on one line doesn't even come close to matching what this program is attempting to do.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I do understand how hard a newbie usually faces to when posting a question on StackOverflow. A lot of down-votings are thrown to his face without any explanations...

Anyway, here is my approach to your problem:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void printZeros(int n) {
    for (int x = 0; x < n; ++x) {
        cout << "0";
    }
    cout << endl;
}

void printZPattern(int n) {
    static int init = n;
    static bool down = true; // true <- down, false <- up

    if (n < 1 || n > init) {
        return;
    }

    printZeros(n);

    if (down) {
        --n;
        if (n < 1) {
            down = false;
            n = 2;
        }
    } else {
        ++n;
    }

    printZPattern(n);
}

int main()
{
    printZPattern(5);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @AAaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa I added a more `recursive` solution that you might like more.

Comment: Your first solution does not meet the actual requirement of the `printZPattern` function being recursive.  Your second solution has side-effects through use of statics.  It is an extremely unsafe and undesirable habit to adopt, especially for something that can be easily solved with pure recursion.  Furthermore, your function does not reset itself, and so will fail to operate correctly if called more than once.

Answer (score 0):

Let's dissect the code you currently have:

1. `count` and `z` are pointless and unused variables, so just remove them.
2. `x` is never modified, so there's no need to store it in `y`.  Again, remove it.
3. There is no such function called `printReverseZ`.  I'm just going to ignore that.
4. `while(x =! 1)` will never execute -- it sets `x` to the value `!1` which is `0` and that immediately evaluates to false.
5. You are not importing the `std` namespace, and do not qualify `cout` and `endl` with their full name -- again, a compilation error.

So what we have is a broken program, which doesn't even compile.  But apparently you got it to run somehow and it doesn't produce the output you desire.

Let me tidy up a bit based on the above points to divine what you *might* have running right now, and then fix it.

```
void printZpattern2(int x)
{
    for (int i=0; i<x; i++)
        std::cout << "0";
    std::cout << std::endl;

    if (x != 1)
        printZpattern2(x - 1);
}
```

Okay, so now this prints the first half:

```
00000
0000
000
00
0
```

It should be obvious by now, that the way to print the second half is to output *after* the recursive call.  *i.e.* once the function has handled all cases down to a single zero.

It's as simple as this:

```
if (x != 1) {
    printZpattern2(x - 1);
    for (int i=0; i<x; i++)
        std::cout << "0";
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

Personally, for a function this simple, I'd just use the `std::string` constructor instead of looping to create the zeroes:

```
void printZpattern2(int x)
{
    if (x <= 0) return;
    std::cout << std::string(x, '0') << std::endl;
    if (x != 1) {
        printZpattern2(x - 1);
        std::cout << std::string(x, '0') << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Notice the extra check I put in, which will avoid problems if you ever called the function with a value of zero or less.